Staying in USA longer than 3 months
My sister is 86, an American citizen, now dying. She is alone after her husband died and in need of care. As the youngest member of our little family, it falls to me to take care of her in her house in Saugerties, NY. I can come to help but if I need to stay longer, what must i do? I don't want to stay in the US (especially if Trump wins in November) and my sister is too frail to leave her house now she has been diagnosed with cancer. I don't want to break any laws, but there is just nobody else who is willing to take care of her. Please can someone advise me?

What is your citizenship?  You have tagged this with [tag:esta].  Do you mean you are a citizen of a country part of the Visa Waiver Programme (VWP)?

AFAIK you need a visa for a longer stay. If you enter the US under the VWP you cannot apply to extend your stay subsequent to entry

Try to ask local consular office. I think they can help to find the best way. From the ages, I assume you will not work illegally or endangers US, which are main concerns.

@GiacomoCatenazzi But on the other hand there are probably no job ties to the home country. Conceivably (to an immigration officer), the OP could decide to stay in the house of her then-deceased sister forever, and potentially become a liability to the tax payers. (No disrespect intended to Patricia to whom I wish all the best, considering the sad circumstances!)

An embassy may honor a request for an expedited handling of a visa application, either as a matter of policy (it looks like e.g. in Denmark such a policy exists for some cases) or as a matter of courtesy (I believe the staff has a certain leeway in prioritizing and deciding). You can make a case of (perhaps extreme) hardship regarding a U.S. citizen (your sister).

If your quest to stay as long as you need does not work out, in the US there are resources for elder care. I'd suggest you start by contacting https://saugerties.ny.us/senior-center. They will likely be able to point you in the direction of local hospice organizations and other resources.

You most likely need to apply for a B-2 visa.
If you are a citizen of a VWP country (who usually only needs a valid ESTA to travel to the US), you cannot use an ESTA in this case because:

It's limited to 3 months
It can't be extended while in the US
You should normally stay outside the US at least as long as you stayed in between successive visits

A B-2 visa will allow you to stay up to 6 months, and request extensions if needed.
Note that you'll still have to give evidence that you are just a visitor and have no intention of staying in the US indefinitely, by showing ties to your country (family, property, ideally a job...), and that you have enough funds to pay for your stay in the US without having to work while you are there. The details will vary greatly based on your exact situation.
Note however that the waiting time for a B-2 appointment varies a lot from one post to another: it's currently only 3 days in Dublin for instance, while it's 110 days in London... and 290 days in Paris!
Also note that if you stay more than 6 months, issues may arise in terms of tax residency. You don't want both the US and your home country to think you owe them tax on your worldwide revenue...
Note: if you are a Canadian citizen the situation may be different, but I don't know the details.

Canadian visitors are always admitted in B-2 (or B-1) status and do not need a visa.  They are not eligible for ESTA nor for the VWP, so they are not limited to 90 days (except potentially in individual cases) and are not prohibited from extending their stay.

@phoog The question was tagged with 'esta' by the OP, so presumably they are not Canadian.

@Doc indeed.  Furthermore, as a consequence of being ineligible for the VWP, Canadians tend to think of "six months" as the allowed duration of stay rather than the "three months" (actually 90 days) that this question asks about.  Yet this answer raised the possibility nonetheless, so it seemed like a good idea to add some of the relevant details.

If OP wants to check waiting times for his location: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html

From your answer and a cursory google it seems like you could get an ESTA and then start the B2 Visa application? So you'd be able to be there for the next 90 days on the ESTA and then hopefully get the B2 sorted ASAP so come back?

@SamDean: that's a bad idea.  The VWP is especially strict.  Those admitted under the VWP (ie with an ESTA) are not eligible to extend their stay or change their status from within the US.  This means that even if later granted a B visa, you still must leave the US within 90 days.  You'd have to leave the US and then re-enter using the B visa, but (1) it's not clear that a short trip to Canada, Mexico or nearby islands would allow you to apply for entry in B status because after such a hop you're usually readmitted in VWP status for the remainder of your original time, and…

(2) leaving and quickly coming back will invite additional scrutiny at immigration, especially if you've already stayed close to 90 days.  Doing this is exactly a visa run, which is very much frowned upon.  It's then up to the discretion of the border officer to let you in with the B visa or deny entry.  Getting turned away because the officer suspects you're abusing the system (or is simply in a bad mood) is not a situation you want to find yourself in.

This is so complicated. I wish we would live in a simpler times.
